# Jquery animate order question

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mousehover

So I've got a logo that changes its background on mousehover, I'm trying to have 5 diferent backgrounds, each one displayed on a mousehover, not randomized and back to the first background when the 5th mousehover is done. How can i achieve this?

Here's the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#logo").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

and the css

```
div#logo{
    background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:216px;
    height:235px;
    position:absolute;
    right:45px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:12;
}

div#logo_hover{
    background-image:url(../images/logo_hover_blue.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:216px;
    height:235px;
    position:absolute;
    right:45px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:11;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've followed Scott M. advice and got this code:

```
$("#logo").click(function () {
  var color = $(this).css("background-image", "background" + bgnum + ".png");
});
```

It's probably missing something...

but the problem is I dont know how to add the other divs (logo1, logo2, logo3, and logo4)with their respective images and keep then invisible until its their turn on mousehover, what's the best way? display:none?

Comment: Edit your question and format your code blocks please.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: sorry bout the blocks
I'm trying to have 5 diferent images on mousehover(each one has a color) to show once and then follow to the second image and so on.. until the fifth image shows up then it restarts to the first image again, is this actually possible? like a changing mousehover, you go over the image and u'll see one color but if you remove your pointer and go over the image again the color changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can maintain a counter (e.g. bgnum) and concatenate it with a file name to get each background. Then on hover you set the css using

```
.css("background-image", "background" + bgnum + ".jpg")
```

then increment the counter, and mod by 5 so it never goes past the number of background that you have.

```
bgnum = (bgnum + 1) % 5;
```

Comment: sorry I'm still a huge newbie on jquery...how exactly would I place the bgnum counter on my code?

Comment: its a variable, independent of jquery, but used in your code. declare it outside of your function as 'var bgnum = 0;'